# How to request data in a 3 Layer architecture?

Tags: architecture, layer

although implicitly moving towards a separation between presentation, logic and data access, I am relatively new to the use of strict 3 Layer architectures. Whilst learning on the topic and reflecting my former projects I came to the question if there is a best practice to request data based on input on the presentation layer.

To be more specific, lets say that it's a C# Windows Forms Application and the DAL reads the requested data from a file. Thus there must be a way for the presentation layer to request the data from the file.

The coarse workflow I imagined would look anything like the following:

- On mouse click on button show OpenFileDialog
- If the user chose a file, pass the name to the BLL
- BLL passes the filename on to the DAL
- DAL reads the file (maybe parses it)
- DAL passes content (or parsed objects) to BLL
- BLL transforms and preprocesses the data
- BLL passes transformed and preprocessed data to PL
- PL presents the data

This seems quite a bit cumbersome to me, but looks like it's being the way to go - at least somehow. Is the approach correct or did I get something horribly wrong?

I am really looking forward to your answers.

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did pretty well....happy to see such understanding...good enough for a beginner I must say. I would like to recommend you the link: http://fewagainstmany.com/blog/introduction-to-layered-architecture-part-one

It will reveal more points to understand better.

Layers are very useful for large code base for enterprise applications to make it maintainable and easy to understand. Once you go deeper about layered architecture and if you are a .NET developer (as I can see), would like to see such a huge code base for an exemplary application at codeplex:  http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/

Thanks and most welcome in case of further queries.

Comment: Not actually a C# beginner, but new to strictly layered architectures, though. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer and your hints on how to proceed.